# How to set a javafx scene to not have a icon?

Tags: java, javafx

Is there a way for a JavaFX stage to NOT display an icon, for it to have no icon?

For example, default windows dialog messages. They have no icon but still display on the taskbar and still have title.

*Sorry if this is a beginner question that is obvious to some, but it seems the ethernet is too small for my basic questions.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can use a different `StageStyle` than the standard `StageStyle.DECORATED` e. g. like this:

```
primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UTILITY); // or StageStyle.UNDECORATED
```

As far as i know there is no support for removing the stage icon on a stage with the decorated style.